# Magento 2 - Trigger "php bin/magento setup:upgrade" from backend

Tags: magento2, setup-upgrade

Is it possible to trigger `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` from the backend? I need to give the company "Amasty" access to our project, so that they can debug a bug in their module, but I am not autorised to give them SSH access.

Comment: "Amasty" is a big brand. Ask your client for this, simple. no waste of time at all. Generate custom ssh with ppk file with allowing few commands only. That will also help you to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not by default in Magento, although you can create your module module that reimplements the logic from the CLI command on a controller action. Or even just call the CLI command via reflection and with dummy interfaces.

The CLI command can be found at `/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/UpgradeCommand.php`

If you do run it by a controller, dependent on your server config, you may need to use message queues to avoid request timeouts. Also dont forget to implement ACL rules.